# Make camera follow x-axis only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to make it follow x-axis only. Only follows y when  I replace with .y .y

It just doesn't want to work, no matter what I try. (Just started game dev today) I'm pretty noob at coding.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float interpVelocity;
    public float minDistance;
    public float followDistance;
    public GameObject target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    Vector3 targetPos;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        targetPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (target)
        {
            Vector3 posNoZ = transform.position;
            posNoZ.z = target.transform.position.z;

            Vector3 targetDirection = (target.transform.position - posNoZ);

            interpVelocity = targetDirection.magnitude * 5f;

            Vector3 factorTowardsTarget = (targetDirection.normalized * interpVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

            targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + factorTowardsTarget.y, transform.position.z);

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos + offset, 0.25f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "does not work"? Impossible to compile, or unable to run, or unexpected results?

Comment: It works, it just follows the y-axis. I want it to follow the X-axis (left and right movements) not up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about what I'm doing either, but I gave it a shot. This is my first post.

From what I understand there's a certain order they have to be in, X then Y then Z. And the Y is what was getting the modifier added to it. I just put the modifier on the X position instead.

I tested it, it seems to work.

I just changed this part:

```
targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + factorTowardsTarget.y, transform.position.z);
```

To this:

```
targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + factorTowardsTarget.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Result:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float interpVelocity;
    public float minDistance;
    public float followDistance;
    public GameObject target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    Vector3 targetPos;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        targetPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (target)
        {
            Vector3 posNoZ = transform.position;
            posNoZ.z = target.transform.position.z;

            Vector3 targetDirection = (target.transform.position - posNoZ);

            interpVelocity = targetDirection.magnitude * 5f;

            Vector3 factorTowardsTarget = (targetDirection.normalized * interpVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

            targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + factorTowardsTarget.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos + offset, 0.25f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Instead of following y axis or x axis it haults mid axis and starts to flow down the axis as it was defined as -y and adding -y makes it float up :D

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the camera follow the object only on the x position

```
public Camera MyCamera; // The camera you want to follow the GameObject
public GameObject ObjectToFollow; // What you want to follow

private Vector3 CameraPos; // Variable that contains the Cameras x,y,z position

void Start()
{
    CameraPos = MyCamera.transform.position; // stores the Camera's position in the variable
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    CameraPos.x = ObjectToFollow.transform.position.x; // Change The X position on the camera variable to be the same as the ObjectToFollow X position
    MyCamera.transform.position = CameraPos; // Moves the Camera to the new position
}
```